# Migration lookup and no stubbing

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a problem with languages and no stubbing regarding migration_lookup plugin in Drupal 8.
I have a different json data, each of them is different languages for example
json with de:

```
data:{ id: 12345, name: 'Product 1 de', id: 123456, name: 'Product 2 de'}
```

json with en

```
data:{ id: 12345, name: 'Product 1 en'}
```

of course this json is only example not validate.

I have a 2 migration yaml file called: migrate_plus.migration.data.yml and migrate_plus.migration.data_de.yml

English version is default version in drupal.

To join de version with en I use process:

```
nid:
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      source: id
      migration: data
      no_stub: true
      stub_id: data
```

I use no_stub: true because i don't want to create stub nodes for not existing en version. Everything works well but only for first time but if I want to update migration I got errors

```
[error]  Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '9424706c-e536-4a59-be13-ebb91367a1a9' for key 'node_field__uuid__value': INSERT INTO {node} (vid, type, uuid, langcode) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3); Array
```

for de version item. In my case I don't want to create new stub item for english version for product 2 de so I though that no_stub option will be ok. Even if I do migrate:rollback I noticed that this migration from de still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that is only in the translation yml, so into **migrate_plus.migration.data_de.yml** you should have:

```
nid:
  plugin: migration_lookup
  source: id
  migration: data
  no_stub: true
```

Also into the same translation file (and only in this one) include the langcode from migrate_plus.migration.data.yml and specify the one for the translation into **process**:

```
langcode:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: de
content_translation_source: en
```

And finally in the end of the **migrate_plus.migration.data_de.yml**:

```
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  translations: true

migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - data
  optional: { }
```